# Test-doubles: what is the name of a "fake" that can be controlled

Tags: java, unit-testing

I've been writing a lot of Java code that uses fakes, but those fakes have controllable behaviour. They tend to fake actual hardware, so an example might be a test where I tell the fake that it should behave as if it's lost comms, or reports a hardware failure. A trivial example:

```
interface CommDevice {
    boolean isConnected();
}

class FakeCommDevice implements CommDevice {
    private boolean connected;
    public boolean isConnected() {return connected;}
    public void setConnected(boolean x) {connected=x;}
}
```

Should I squirrel the controlling code away into a new interface? E.g.

```
class FakeCommDevice implements CommDevice {
    public class Manager () {
        public void setConnected(boolean x) {connected=x;}
    }
    private boolean connected;
    public boolean isConnected() {return connected;}
    public Manager manager() {return new Manager();}
}
```

These classes are certainly a sub-set of fakes, but they exclude other classes that are fakes. Is there a suitable terminology to describe them?

Comment: Your question is too vague...  Anyways your second class is illegal because if the class is private you cannot return it as a public member

Comment: You are asking two rather unrelated questions, one asking a design question and the second for terminology. You should only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

Call them [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) or just "mocks".

Answer (score 0):

You would effectively be adding new functionality to your 'fake' (better known as 'mock')  class which would make your code a little misleading. Stick with the same interface, and then look at Mockito if you haven't already.